# Store WIFI Credentials

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

When I call `WiFi.begin(ssid, pass)`, it saves your credentials. So next time your sketch runs, it will connect automatically.

But if I call `WiFi.config(IP, Gate, Subnet)` before that, it connects without using the DHCP server.
But after restart it's using DHCP again.

It seems to me that the `WiFi.config` parameters are not stored anywhere for further usage. Am I right? What should I do to store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store WiFi credentials and IP settings, you would use SPIFFS. I suggest you also to store SSID and pass in a file despite WiFi core stores it.

Here is basic file operation on SPIFFS to store some data on it :

```
#include "FS.h"
SPIFFS.begin();
File configFile = SPIFFS.open("config.txt", "w+");
if (configFile) 
{
  configFile.println(IP);
  configFile.println(WiFi.SSID());
  // and so on ..
}
configFile.close();
```

Please consider the file r/w operation options declared in the [SPIFFS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.md) doc.

Here is also a good [config file example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/489a7e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/libraries/esp8266/examples/ConfigFile/ConfigFile.ino) with JSON.